# CodeIgniter performance issues with large form

Tags: php, performance, forms, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and I have some performance issues with a very large form. Basically it can reach 1,000 fields because it's used for data entry (many of the fields have the same value so the user spends less than 30min filling it thanks to client-side code).

It takes less than a second to show the form populated from the DB. But when the user clicks on submit, the exact same code that now takes the POST data instead of DB data takes forever and usually times out. It works fine for a few hundred fields (taking less than 15s to submit/insert in DB) but if the number of fields is doubled it suddenly takes much, much longer.

There are 3 parts in the code (which I won't copy here because it's very long and complex due to all the logic involved in so many fields):

1. Prepare the data (from DB or form) inside objects
2. Form validation using `$this->form_validation->run()`
3. DB inserts/edits

Part 1 is very fast when the data is read from the DB for an edit. When the data comes from POST, it never reaches part 2 so it's definitely not an issue with form validation or DB inserts.

As I sometimes get this message, I think the issue comes from the XSS protection from Codeigniter:

```
Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in (...)/system/core/Security.php
```

Do you know if using any of these is a bit slow? `$this->post->input('fieldname', TRUE)` and `$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE)`. Does Codeigniter do a lot of calculations each time I use them and should I therefore save each post input into a variable before using them in calculations?

Alternatively I could turn off XSS protection since it's in our admin part but I'd really not go that way.

Or maybe it's not that at all and my code is somehow poor?

Comment: Have you tried [Profiling](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html) your application or using the [Benchmarking Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/benchmark.html)? This may help you work out which parts of your code, if any, are particularly slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! Basically I added this at the start of my controller:

```
if($this->input->post(NULL,TRUE)) $hasPOST = true;
else $hasPOST = false;
```

And I replaced every single instance of `if($this->input->post(NULL,TRUE)) {do some stuff}` by `if($hasPOST) {do some stuff}`.

It now takes under a second to submit... The issue with using `if($this->input->post(NULL,TRUE))` to check if there was some post data was that codeigniter ran the xss cleaning on ALL fields each time.

Answer (score 0):

well i would look back at your user scenario again, is it really necessary to submit all 1000 values in one go? or could you break it down into a multi-step process for the user. It seems a lot of data to be processing to me.

I would time your script to see where your choke points are, it maybe nothing to do with codeIgniter but purely because you are trying to submit such a large amount of fields.

Comment: My backup solution will indeed be to break the form into several parts but this will mean refactoring the whole thing without really understanding what the issue was in the first place so ideally it doesn't get to that point.

Comment: I have been timing the script and it now appears that if I have e.g 400 fields it will take 15s but if I have  800 fields it will not even go through the main loop 50 times. So I highly suspect that using this in my loop is very, very bad for performance: if($this->input->post(NULL,TRUE)). I think codeigniter does xss cleaning on all forms each time this is called, which degrades performance when called in a loop (it would then do 800x800 cleaning...).